# Underbrace under sqrt content

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath

I am trying to use `underbrace` to clarify the arguments to a `sqrt`. However this causes the square root sign to reach all the way down to the bottom of the text under the brace(s), which is not what I want.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$\sqrt{\underbrace{\frac{1}{\tau}\underbrace{\int_{\text{-}\infty}^{t}\underbrace{p_{X}^{\,2}\left(\xi\right)\cdot e^{\frac{\text{-}\left(t\text{-}\xi\right)}{\tau}}}_{\substack{\text{Expontial}\\\text{time-weighting}\\\text{of $p_{X}^{\,2}\left(\xi\right)$}}} \,\mathrm{d}\xi}_{\text{Exponential integration}}}_{\substack{\text{Exponential averaging}\\\text{= “Quasi mean-square”}}}}$

\end{document}
```

This results in something like this:

[image: sqrt pulled down by underbracing]

Does anyone know how I can force `sqrt` to reach only as low as its actual (mathematically speaking) argument?

Comment: For smaller pieces of text, it is worth mentioning the easier appraoch taken here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308962

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would recommend Mico's way; if you really want the surd, then here is a solution that takes all the vertical space it needs (not like in wh1t3's answer):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\def\sqrtexplained#1{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{$#1$}
    \def\underbrace##1_##2{##1}
    \sbox2{$#1$}
    \dimen0=\wd0 \advance\dimen0-\wd2
    \mathrlap{\sqrt{\phantom{\displaystyle#1}\kern\dimen0 }}
    \hphantom{\sqrt{\vphantom{\displaystyle#1}}}
  \endgroup
  #1}


\begin{document}

\[
\sqrtexplained{%
\underbrace{\frac{1}{\tau}
  \underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{t}
    \underbrace{p_{X}^{2}(\xi)\cdot e^{\frac{-(t-\xi)}{\tau}}}
    _{\substack{\text{Exponential}\\
                \text{time-weighting}\\
                \text{of $p_{X}^{2}(\xi)$}}
     }
   \,\mathrm{d}\xi}
   _{\text{Exponential integration}}}
_{\substack{\text{Exponential averaging}\\
            =\text{Quasi mean-square}}
 }
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've also corrected the input errors you are making: `\text{-}` for a minus sign is wrong; `\left` and `\right` should be used only when they are really needed.

Comment: Works great, thanks! However, is it possible you forgot a `\makeatother`?

Comment: @Matthias Delete the `\makeatletter`, it's not needed (I already did in the answer).

Answer (score 14):

I would suggest that you *not* use the `\sqrt{...}` symbolism at all because it adds yet another horizontal bar to an expression that's already very busy-looking. Instead, I suggest you write something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{concrete,eulervm,mathtools}
\begin{document}
$ \biggl(\,
   \underbrace{\frac{1}{\tau} 
   \underbrace{\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}
   \underbrace{p_{X}^{\,2} (\xi) \cdot e^{-(t-\xi)/\tau}}
      _{\substack{\text{Exponential time-}\\
                  \text{weighting of $p_{X}^{\,2}(\xi)$}}} 
   \,d\xi}
      _{\text{Exponential integration}}}
      _{\substack{\text{Exponential averaging}\\
                  \text{$=$ ``Quasi mean-square''}}}
  \,\biggr)^{1/2} $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I considered doing it like that, but because I use square root signs elsewhere in the document I would prefer to do so here as well for consistency.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `\smash` and a `\vphantom` to make it work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[\sqrt{\vphantom{\int_{\text{-}\infty}^{t}x}\smash{
  \underbrace{
    \frac{1}{\tau}
    \underbrace{
      \int_{\text{-}\infty}^{t}
      \underbrace{
        p_{X}^{\,2}\left(\xi\right)\cdot e^{\frac{\text{-}\left(t\text{-}\xi\right)}{\tau}}
        }_{\substack{\text{Expontial}\\\text{time-weighting}\\\text{of $p_{X}^{\,2}\left(\xi\right)$}}} \,\mathrm{d}\xi
      }_{\text{Exponential integration}}
    }_{\substack{\text{Exponential averaging}\\\text{= “Quasi mean-square”}}}
  }}\]

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image: correctly sized sqrt]

I should note that this does not appear to work in inline math-mode. The size of the `vphantom` does not correctly reflect the integral sign then. Perhaps someone else can explain why this is the case, since I don't know.

**Edit** after @egreg's comment, an additional vphantom should be added, to ensure the displaymath gets the height of the braces as well. The modified code would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[\sqrt{\vphantom{\int_{\text{-}\infty}^{t}x}\smash{
  \underbrace{
    \frac{1}{\tau}
    \underbrace{
      \int_{\text{-}\infty}^{t}
      \underbrace{
        p_{X}^{\,2}\left(\xi\right)\cdot e^{\frac{\text{-}\left(t\text{-}\xi\right)}{\tau}}
        }_{\substack{\text{Expontial}\\\text{time-weighting}\\\text{of $p_{X}^{\,2}\left(\xi\right)$}}} \,\mathrm{d}\xi
      }_{\text{Exponential integration}}
    }_{\substack{\text{Exponential averaging}\\\text{= “Quasi mean-square”}}}
  }}
  \vphantom{\underbrace{
    \frac{1}{\tau}
    \underbrace{
      \int_{\text{-}\infty}^{t}
      \underbrace{
        p_{X}^{\,2}\left(\xi\right)\cdot e^{\frac{\text{-}\left(t\text{-}\xi\right)}{\tau}}
        }_{\substack{\text{Expontial}\\\text{time-weighting}\\\text{of $p_{X}^{\,2}\left(\xi\right)$}}} \,\mathrm{d}\xi
      }_{\text{Exponential integration}}
    }_{\substack{\text{Exponential averaging}\\\text{= “Quasi mean-square”}}}
  }
  \]

  A long sentence after it to see if there are problems with overruning.

\end{document}
```

And its output like this:

[image]

Comment: An added `\displaystyle` ought to do it.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap yes, I gathered that from Stefan's answer as well. Why is this the case though? The actual integral in the formula is not set in displaystyle, so why would it need the additional height in the vphantom, when it clearly does not require it for the actual formula?

Comment: This doesn't give the formula its real vertical size; subsequent text will be superposed to it.

Comment: @egreg you are absolutely right, added a `vphantom` to handle this.

Answer (score 7):

Seems to be missing a `tikz` solution:

[image]

or with smaller text under the brace:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

% Tweak these as necessary
\newcommand*{\BraceAmplitude}{0.4em}%
\newcommand*{\VerticalOffset}{0.8ex}%  
\newcommand*{\HorizontalOffset}{0.0em}% 


\NewDocumentCommand{\InsertUnderBrace}{%
    O{} % #1 = draw options
    O{yshift=0.0cm} % #2 = optional brace shift options
    m   % #3 = left tikzmark
    m   % #4 = right tikzmark
    m   % #5 = text to place under brace
}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw [densely dotted, draw=blue, text=black, #1] 
        ($(#4)+(\HorizontalOffset,-\VerticalOffset)$) --
        ([#2]$(#4)+(\HorizontalOffset,-\VerticalOffset)$);
    \draw [decoration={brace, amplitude=\BraceAmplitude}, decorate, thick, draw=blue, text=black, #1]
        ([#2]$(#4)+( \HorizontalOffset,-\VerticalOffset)$) -- 
        ([#2]$(#3)+(-\HorizontalOffset,-\VerticalOffset)$)
        node [below=\VerticalOffset, midway, align=center] {#5};
    \draw [densely dotted, draw=blue, text=black, #1] 
        ([#2]$(#3)+(-\HorizontalOffset,-\VerticalOffset)$) --
        ($(#3)+(\HorizontalOffset,-\VerticalOffset)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\newcommand*{\MyEquation}{%
    \tikzmark{StartBraceC}
    \sqrt{%
        \frac{1}{\tau} 
        \tikzmark{StartBraceB}
        \int_{\text{-}\infty}^{t} 
            \tikzmark{StartBraceA}
                p_{X}^{2}
                \left(\xi\right)
                \cdot e^{\frac{\text{-}\left(t\text{-}\xi\right)}{\tau}} 
            \tikzmark{EndBraceA}
            \mathrm{d}\xi
        \tikzmark{EndBraceB}
    }
    \hspace*{0.5em}\tikzmark{EndBraceC}
}
\begin{document}
\[ \MyEquation \]
%
\InsertUnderBrace[draw=red,text=red]{StartBraceA}{EndBraceA}
    {Exponential \\ time-weighting \\ of $p_{X}^{\,2}\left(\xi\right)$}
%
\InsertUnderBrace[draw=olive,text=olive][yshift=-1.5cm]{StartBraceB}{EndBraceB}
    {Exponential \\ integration}
%
\InsertUnderBrace[draw=blue,text=blue][yshift=-2.5cm]{StartBraceC}{EndBraceC}
    {Exponential averaging \\= ``Quasi mean-square"}
%
\vspace*{3.0cm}\par
\bigskip\noindent
or with smaller text
\[ \MyEquation \]
%
\InsertUnderBrace[draw=red,text=red, font=\tiny]{StartBraceA}{EndBraceA}
    {Exponential time-\\weighting of $p_{X}^{\,2}\left(\xi\right)$}
%
\InsertUnderBrace[draw=olive,text=olive, font=\tiny][yshift=-0.8cm]{StartBraceB}{EndBraceB}
    {Exponential integration}
%
\InsertUnderBrace[draw=blue,text=blue, font=\tiny][yshift=-1.4cm]{StartBraceC}{EndBraceC}
    {Exponential averaging = ``Quasi mean-square"}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very pretty :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to have nice looking braces then you can use the following brute force method.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\(\sqrt{\frac{1}{\tau}\int_{-\infty}^{t} p_{X}^{2}(\xi)\cdot e^{t-\xi}d\xi}\)
\psbrace[rot=90, braceWidthInner=5pt, braceWidthOuter=5pt, nodesepB=8pt, nodesepA=-15pt]   (-2.5,-.2)(-.5,-.2){some text}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]