# Curly brackets around a table

Tags: tables, braces

I would like to have braces on the left side of a table (either that or on the right side) and bellow the same table.

What I have got is

```
$
m-Mal 
\underbrace{
  \left\{\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}\hline
   1+1 & 1+2 & ... & 1+n \\ \hline
   2+1 & 2+2 & ... & 2+n \\ \hline
   ... & ... & ... & ... \\ \hline
   m+1 & m+2 & ... & m+n \\ \hline
   \end{tabular}
   }_{n-Mal}
$
```

But the problem is that the underbrace goes too much to the left:

[image]

Ideally, the `\underbrace` would end where the first column starts.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I added the image for you.

Comment: Related: [parenthesis around underbrace too big](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86600)

Comment: German? Typographically and orthographically speaking, `n\text{-mal}` would be correct (upright `-mal`; `-` being a hypen, not a minus; [`m` a minuscule](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mal); requires `\usepackage{amsmath}`). Also, in the underbrace’s text, I’d add `\textstyle` (i.e. `_{\textstyle n\text{-mal}}`) so that it has the same size as _n_-mal.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel thank you (I'm not a native so I make lots of those small grammar mistakes) ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's on option, with some modifications to your current arrangement:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  m-Mal 
  \underbrace{
  \left\{\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}\hline
   1+1 & 1-2 & ... & 1+n \\ \hline
   2+1 & 2+2 & ... & 2+n \\ \hline
   ... & ... & ... & ... \\ \hline
   m+1 & m+2 & ... & m+n \\ \hline
   \end{tabular}\right.
   }_{n-Mal}
\]
\[
  % Store contents in \box0
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\begin{array}{|*{4}{c|}}\hline
    1+1 & 1-2 & \cdots & 1+n \\ \hline
    2+1 & 2+2 & \cdots & 2+n \\ \hline
    \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\ \hline
    m+1 & m+2 & \cdots & m+n \\ \hline
    \end{array}$}
  m-Mal\left\{\vphantom{\usebox0}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  \underbrace{\usebox0}_{n-Mal}
\]
\end{document}
```

I've used

- `array` instead of `tabular` since the content seemed math-related;
- `\cdots` instead of `...`;
- a column specification that is easily identifiable and changeable (`|*{4}{c|}`);
- a box to store the entire structure (`\box0`), then used it to insert the left brace at the appropriate size (via a `\vphantom`). This leaves you to use a regular `\underbrace` to obtain the correct length.

A minor correction in terms of spacing is required to adjust for the "missing" right delimiter `\right.`.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. I just don't get what exactly does the \kern do.

Comment: @smihael `\kern<glue>` Adds a space (horizontal or vertical depending on context, here it's horizontal), and `\nulldelimiterspace` is the width of `\right.`