# How to typeset this in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I would like to typeset the following matrix:

[image]

However, I don't know how to achieve the braces and the dots leading to the matrix entry.

Comment: Does [Curly brackets around a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86792) give you an idea?

Comment: You might also find useful [Add a curved arrow and a bracket to a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117873/13304).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\begin{document}
\[
  \Phi =
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\scriptstyle\text{states}$}
  \end{tabular}
  \mleft\{
    \vphantom{%
      \begin{bmatrix}
        \vdots \\
        \phi_{iy} \\
        \vdots
      \end{bmatrix}
    }%
  \mright.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  j % \,
  \overbrace{%
    \mathop{%
      \!
      \begin{bmatrix}
        \vdots \\
        \cdots \phi_{iy} \hphantom{\cdots} \\
        \vphantom{\vdots}
      \end{bmatrix}
      \!
    }\limits^{\smash{\textstyle y}}
  }^{\text{aggr. states}}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The matrix is set using environment `bmatrix` of package `amsmath` that automatically sets the brackets.
- `\text` of package `amsmath` (or `amstext`) sets text in text mode (automatically resized).
- `\mleft` and `\mright` of package `mleftright` avoid the additional surrounding space of `\left` and `\right`.
- `\vphantom` creates an emtpy box with width zero, but the height and depth of its argument. Thus the left brace only covers the matrix, not the stuff above.
- `\right.` is an invisible right delimiter. TeX inserts the space `\nulldelimiterspace`, thus `\kern-\nulldelimiterspace` removes the space.
- `\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}...\end{tabular}` is a trick to center the box around the math axis. (Internally `\vcenter` is used.)
- The side bearings of the big left and right brackets are quite large. Thus the horizontal brace is a little wider than necessary (thanks Barbara Beeton for noticing). This is fixed by a negative space `\!` before and after the matrix. A `\,` could be inserted after `j` to keep the space to the matrix constant. But I have commented it, because a smaller distance looks better IMHO.

Comment: much better :-)

Comment: You solve the problem of the different size of the two labels with `\scriptstyle` command, can you what this command does?

Comment: @Red: The four math style commands control the size of math, the position of limits for math operators and so on. `\displaystyle` is used for displayed equations, `\textstyle` for inline math, but with the same sizes. The next smaller size is `\scriptstyle`, used in sub- and superscripts. In case of further nesting, `\scriptscriptstyle` is the smallest math style.

Comment: the horizontal brace is a little wider than needed. probably owing to some built-in spacing around the brackets..

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks, I have fixed it manually using `\!`.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} %for the \rotatebox command
\begin{document}
\[
\setbox0=\hbox{
    $\begin{array}{c}
        y\\
        j\begin{bmatrix}
            & \vdots &  \\
            \cdots & \Phi_{jy} & \\
            & &  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{array}$
}
\Phi = \text{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{states}}\left\{\vphantom{\usebox0}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\overbrace{\usebox0}^\text{aggr. states}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The two labels appear to be slightly different font sizes.

Comment: The 'y' is not aligned with the downward-facing ellipsis. Shouldn't the center line of the ellipsis be the same as the (horizontal) center of the y and the $\Phi_{i,j}$?