# braces over matrix

Tags: matrices, braces, bordermatrix

I want to make an overbrace and a side brace on my matrix in order to indicate its size. How can I achieve that.

```
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 0 & .& . & . & 0 & 1  \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & .& . & . & 1 & 0 \\
 .\\
 .\\
 .\\
  0 & 1 & 1 & . & . & . & 1 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}
```

Comment: See here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129775/31093
It is not exactly your situation but I think you can use it to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's one way... [EDITED, added `\mkern` to address barbara's concern; REEDITED to make use of `\overbrace` superscript]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\def\tmp{%
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 0 & .& . & . & 0 & 1  \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & .& . & . & 1 & 0 \\
 .\\
 .\\
 .\\
  0 & 1 & 1 & . & . & . & 1 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}
}%
\[
\stackMath\def\stackalignment{r}%
  \stackon%
    {\mathrm{10~rows}\left\{\tmp\right.}%
    {\overbrace{\phantom{\smash{\tmp\mkern -36mu}}}^{\mathrm{\textstyle 12~columns}}\mkern 20mu}%
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The following requires some `\nulldelimiterspace` corrections, but only uses [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\def\matriximg{%
  \begin{matrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1 & 0 \\
    \cdot                                     \\
    \cdot                                     \\
    \cdot                                     \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1 & 1
   \end{matrix}
}%
\[
  \text{\scriptsize 10~rows}\left\{\left(\vphantom{\matriximg}\right.\right.\kern-2\nulldelimiterspace
  \overbrace{\matriximg}^{\text{12 columns}}\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\left.\vphantom{\matriximg}\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

For raising the `\overbrace` slightly, you could use

```
\vphantom{\raisebox{.25\baselineskip}{$\matriximg$}}\matriximg
```

Comment: I need only the overbrace and not the side brace. kindly explain which is the one for overbrace and which one is for side brace.

Comment: @user27665: Use [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/zqLPNyB2).

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you can do with `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 6.4 of 2021/11/23).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$10$ rows $\left\{
\begin{pNiceMatrix}
   1 & 1 & 0 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 0 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1 & 0 \\
   \cdot                                     \\
   \cdot                                     \\
   \cdot                                     \\
   0 & 1 & 1 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1 & 1
\CodeAfter
   \OverBrace[yshift=1.5mm,shorten]{1-1}{1-last}{12 \text{ columns}}
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\right.$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

I would use a finer and cleaner option by employing the known \overbrace which allows you to achieve your results very easily.

Here is a small example

```
$$
\overbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    \epsilon[1]\\
    \epsilon[2]\\
    \vdots \\
    \epsilon[M]
    \end{bmatrix}}^{a}
$$
```

Comment: Note the question asks for a "side brace" as well. Can you update your answer to address this as well?