# Aligning different matrices

Tags: vertical-alignment, matrices

I want to write the companion matrix of a recurrence relation and its use (the notation will be a bit unusual since it is "for cryptography", where we always do stuff in a different way).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  C :=
   \begin{pmatrix}
   0      & 1      & 0      & \cdots & 0 \\
   0      & 0      & 1      & \cdots & 0 \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
   0      & 0      & 0      & \ddots & 1 \\
   c_0    & c_1    & c_2    & \cdots & c_{n-1}  \\
  \end{pmatrix}
%%%
    \quad\textrm{and}\quad
%%%
  C \cdot
  \begin{pmatrix}
  y_{k} \\ y_{k+1} \\ \vdots \\ y_{n+k-2} \\ y_{n+k-1} \\
   \end{pmatrix}
=
  \begin{pmatrix}
  y_{k+1} \\ y_{k+2} \\ \vdots \\ y_{n+k-1} \\ y_{n+k} \\
   \end{pmatrix}
   \enspace.
\]

\end{document}
```

however, the square matrix is taller than the column vectors. How can I make everything align nicely?

[image: rendering of above code]

Roberto

EDIT: Thank you all folks, in my case it was the wrong \ddots (ahem).

EDIT 2:

So, merging @percusse's suggestion with [braces over matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130798/braces-over-matrix) I came up with this

```
\def\matriximg{%
    \begin{array}{c|ccc}
      \\
      \vphantom{\vdots} 0 &\multicolumn{3}{c}{I_{n-1}} \\
      \\ \hline
      \vphantom{y_k} c_0  & c_1 & \ldots &c_{n-1}
    \end{array}
}%
\begin{equation}
 \label{eq:companion}
  \left(\vphantom{\matriximg}\right.%
  \kern-2\nulldelimiterspace%
  \underbrace{\matriximg}_{\displaystyle C}%
  \kern-\nulldelimiterspace%
  \left.\vphantom{\matriximg}\right)%
%
  \cdot
%
     \left(\!\begin{array}{c}
     y_{k} \\ \hline y_{k+1} \\ \vdots  \\ y_{n+k-1} \\
     \end{array}\!\right)
  =
     \left(\!\begin{array}{c}
     y_{k+1} \\ \vdots \\ y_{n+k-1} \\ \hline y_{n+k} \\
     \end{array}\!\right)
  \enspace.
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Do you need the diagonal dots in row 4 column 4? If you replace them by `\cdots`, all problems are gone.

Comment: Uh, @LaRIFaRi, thank you, that was the problem. Cough cough. The other solutions are nice as well and contain elements that will definitely prove useful in my further TeXing!

Comment: Nice! But horizontal lines are guiding the reader for the size property so you don't need the subscript of identity matrix. I would trust the reader instead. In my notes, I even remove the indices of the shifted part of the vectors and place a single character to indicate. Might a bit too much for your audience though.

Answer (score 4):

Curious.  It turns out `\ddots` is slightly higher than other characters.  I suggest `\smash` ing them in the first matrix:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  C \coloneqq
   \begin{pmatrix}
   0      & 1      & 0      & \cdots & 0 \\
   0      & 0      & 1      & \cdots & 0 \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \smash{\ddots} & \vdots \\
   0      & 0      & 0      & \smash{\ddots} & 1 \\
   c_0    & c_1    & c_2    & \cdots & c_{n-1} 
  \end{pmatrix}
%%%
    \quad\textrm{and}\quad
%%%
  C \cdot
  \begin{pmatrix}
   y_{k} \\  y_{k+1} \\ \vdots \\ 
  y_{n+k-2} \\  y_{n+k-1} 
   \end{pmatrix}
   =
  \begin{pmatrix}
   y_{k+1} \\ y_{k+2} \\ \vdots \\ y_{n+k-1} \\ y_{n+k} \\
   \end{pmatrix}
   .
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I have used `mathtools` just get the `\coloneqq` symbol.

Comment: Yes, this is more elegant. `\ddots` is more then two times higher than `y_{n+k-2}`. I guess, they got some extra space above and below in order to get nicer spacings. The same for `\vdots`. Therefore you have to smash all dots in the middle row or leave the whole row as it is.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to replace the `\ddots` in row 4 by `\cdots`. I think, this makes more sense but maybe you need it this way.

The problem is that the `\ddots` are higher than the expressions in row 4 of the second and third term. If you increase the height of these expressions as shown in my MWE below, the alignment will be fixed again. If you want to distribute the rows more evenly, you could add such a `\vphantom{\ddots}` to the other rows, too.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  C :=
   \begin{pmatrix}
   0      & 1      & 0      & \cdots & 0 \\
   0      & 0      & 1      & \cdots & 0 \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
   0      & 0      & 0      & \ddots & 1 \\
   c_0    & c_1    & c_2    & \cdots & c_{n-1}  \\
  \end{pmatrix}
%%%
    \quad\textrm{and}\quad
%%%
  C \cdot
  \begin{pmatrix}
  y_{k} \\ y_{k+1} \\ \vdots \\ y_{n+k-2}\vphantom{\ddots} \\ y_{n+k-1} \\
   \end{pmatrix}
=
  \begin{pmatrix}
  y_{k+1} \\ y_{k+2} \\ \vdots \\ y_{n+k-1}\vphantom{\ddots} \\ y_{n+k} \\
   \end{pmatrix}
   \enspace.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

`\ddots` and `\vdots` are enlarged by round about 50 % on the top and the bottom. This shall result in nicer spacing for typical dotted matrices. Maybe there are cropped dot-symbols around, but I haven't checked that.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, in my ignorant opinion, the dots are ugly and making the matrix unreadable even when you have the most basic companion structure in the state matrix. Here is something that is more appealing to my taste which emphasizes the shift operation;

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
\underbrace{\left(
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\\0   &\multicolumn{3}{c}I\\ 
\\ \hline c_0 &c_1 &\ldots &c_{n-1}
\end{array}
\right)}_C\cdot
  \left(\begin{array}{c}
  y_{k} \\ \hline y_{k+1} \\ \vdots  \\ y_{n+k-1} \\
   \end{array}\right)
=
  \left(\begin{array}{c}
  y_{k+1} \\ \vdots \\ y_{n+k-1} \\\hline y_{n+k} \\
   \end{array}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is indeed nice. Since I am a fine typography freak, I may end up adopting this ;-)

Comment: @mocenigo By all means. We need to increase the number of the members of the club :P