# band diagonal Matrix

Tags: matrices

How can I represent this matrix in latex ?
[image]

Comment: Just as any other matrix with `\begin{bmatrix} ... \end{bmatrix}`.  For the braces this might be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130798/braces-over-matrix

Comment: You'll get better help if you explain what you have got so far, and what specifically you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you need the matrix for fixed `n` and `k` or do you need exactly what is shown on your drawing?

Answer (score 2):

You might find this useful.  As for adding a big 0, you can overlay with \smash and \rlap (or use a tikzpicture).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

%from page 117 of symbols.pdf
\makeatletter
\def\revddots{\mathinner{\mkern1mu\raise\p@
\vbox{\kern7\p@\hbox{.}}\mkern2mu
\raise4\p@\hbox{.}\mkern2mu\raise7\p@\hbox{.}\mkern1mu}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \cdots & 1\\
\vdots & \revddots & \vdots\\
1 & \cdots & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]