# How to get a single big right brace?

Tags: equations, matrices, braces, amsart

I am trying to make the right brace cover the whole matrix like the `\overbrace'. Is there a way to do this?

```
\documentclass[reqno,12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage[top=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\author{something}
\title{something}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{something}
 \begin{equation}
    \mathbf{G}=\overbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    0&0&0&0&0\\
    0&0&0&0&0\\
    0.271&0&0&0&0\\
    0.498&0.271&0&0&0\\
    0.687&0.498&0.271&0&0\\
    0.845&0.687&0.498&0.271&0\\
    0.977&0.845&0.687&0.498&0.271\\
    1.087&0.977&0.845&0.687&0.498\\
    1.179&1.087&0.977&0.845&0.687\\
    1.256&1.179&1.087&0.977&0.845
    \end{bmatrix}}^{\text{something 1}} \Biggr\rbrace
  \text{something 2}
 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Something that works like `\right\rbrace`. Unfortunately you can't use `\right` alone.
There is a workaround here [tex.stackexchange.com/q/130798/156344](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130798/156344). I would appreciate it if someone could tell me how to translate the TeX to LateX used there.

Comment: `\left.` `\right\}`?

Comment: I just need the right brace. Not the left one

Comment: Yes. `\left.` doesn't produce anything. However, honestly this way is very bad. Consider something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130798/156344

Comment: I see. It looks ugly with the \left. \right. Thanks for the link. I will look into it.

Comment: It is not so ugly if you use `\left \right` a bit more carefully. The problem is the horizontal brace.

Comment: I don't understand your latter question. Both answers in the linked question are in LaTeX. TeX is not related at all

Comment: @JouleV I see. It's just the commands. They are like the ones used in the TeXbook rather than the companion book which I am more familiar with, hence my uneducated question. I haven't have had the time to read the TeXbook yet. I'm not really sure whether it's necessary or not.

Comment: The TeX commands are very different. Actually TeX is far harder. Those command are just advanced LaTeX commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can do with `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 6.4 of 2021-11-23):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[ \mathbf{G} = 
\begin{bNiceMatrix}
  0&0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&0&0&0\\
  0.271&0&0&0&0\\
  0.498&0.271&0&0&0\\
  0.687&0.498&0.271&0&0\\
  0.845&0.687&0.498&0.271&0\\
  0.977&0.845&0.687&0.498&0.271\\
  1.087&0.977&0.845&0.687&0.498\\
  1.179&1.087&0.977&0.845&0.687\\
  1.256&1.179&1.087&0.977&0.845
\CodeAfter 
  \OverBrace{1-1}{10-5}{\text{something 1}}[yshift=1mm,shorten]
  \SubMatrix{.}{1-1}{10-5}{\}}[right-xshift=1mm,extra-height=-1mm]
\end{bNiceMatrix}\quad \text{something 2}\]

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 4):

Writing in your style:

```
\documentclass[reqno,12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage[top=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\author{something}
\title{something}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{something}
 \begin{equation}
 \newcommand\yourmatrix{\begin{bmatrix}
    0&0&0&0&0\\
    0&0&0&0&0\\
    0.271&0&0&0&0\\
    0.498&0.271&0&0&0\\
    0.687&0.498&0.271&0&0\\
    0.845&0.687&0.498&0.271&0\\
    0.977&0.845&0.687&0.498&0.271\\
    1.087&0.977&0.845&0.687&0.498\\
    1.179&1.087&0.977&0.845&0.687\\
    1.256&1.179&1.087&0.977&0.845
\end{bmatrix}}
    \mathbf{G}=\overbrace{\yourmatrix}^{\text{something 1}}\left.\vphantom{\yourmatrix}\right\}{\scriptstyle\text{something 2}}
 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

In this way, the vertical brace is good, but it is a little painful to have it. The horizontal brace is not good because it groups the whole matrix (with brackets). Consider some methods used in [braces over matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130798/156344) and similar questions.

[image]

---

This is a good modification of it, but this is a bit overkill. Literally you can't avoid defining a macro if you follow this way.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
 \newcommand\yourmatrix{\begin{matrix}
    0&0&0&0&0\\
    0&0&0&0&0\\
    0.271&0&0&0&0\\
    0.498&0.271&0&0&0\\
    0.687&0.498&0.271&0&0\\
    0.845&0.687&0.498&0.271&0\\
    0.977&0.845&0.687&0.498&0.271\\
    1.087&0.977&0.845&0.687&0.498\\
    1.179&1.087&0.977&0.845&0.687\\
    1.256&1.179&1.087&0.977&0.845
\end{matrix}}
    \mathbf{G}=\left[\vphantom{\yourmatrix}\right.\overbrace{\yourmatrix}^{\text{something 1}}\left.\vphantom{\yourmatrix}\right]\left.\vphantom{\yourmatrix}\right\}{\scriptstyle\text{something 2}}
 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Using `savebox` (hope I get it right – please correct me if not)

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}
\newsavebox{\yourmatrix}
\begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
 \sbox{\yourmatrix}{$\begin{matrix}
    0&0&0&0&0\\
    0&0&0&0&0\\
    0.271&0&0&0&0\\
    0.498&0.271&0&0&0\\
    0.687&0.498&0.271&0&0\\
    0.845&0.687&0.498&0.271&0\\
    0.977&0.845&0.687&0.498&0.271\\
    1.087&0.977&0.845&0.687&0.498\\
    1.179&1.087&0.977&0.845&0.687\\
    1.256&1.179&1.087&0.977&0.845
\end{matrix}$}
    \mathbf{G}=\left[\vphantom{\usebox{\yourmatrix}}\right.\overbrace{\usebox{\yourmatrix}}^{\text{something 1}}\left.\vphantom{\usebox{\yourmatrix}}\right]\left.\vphantom{\usebox{\yourmatrix}}\right\}{\scriptstyle\text{something 2}}
 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

(same output as above)

Comment: You could make \yourmatrix a savebox instead of a macro.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Actually I read the linked question even before my attempts to answer this one. Both answers there use macros, so I am inspired :))

Comment: I'd set the definition of `\yourmatrix` insde the `equation` environment itself, so it's local to the environment and not far from its usage. Having it in the preamble makes changes more awkward. This is even more necessary if you use the `\sbox` strategy, because math fonts might get chosen at begin document.

Comment: @egreg Yes, you are right. Localization is needed in this case, or we will need to define a hundred of different `\yourmatrix`s - maybe running out of name.

Answer (score 4):

Saveboxes are basically pre-formatted text, and are therefore faster than expanding a macro.  More to the point, one can extract the width, height and depth directly.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}
\newsavebox{\yourmatrix}
\savebox{\yourmatrix}{$\begin{matrix}
    0&0&0&0&0\\
    0&0&0&0&0\\
    0.271&0&0&0&0\\
    0.498&0.271&0&0&0\\
    0.687&0.498&0.271&0&0\\
    0.845&0.687&0.498&0.271&0\\
    0.977&0.845&0.687&0.498&0.271\\
    1.087&0.977&0.845&0.687&0.498\\
    1.179&1.087&0.977&0.845&0.687\\
    1.256&1.179&1.087&0.977&0.845
\end{matrix}$}
\newcommand{\vphantombox}[1]{\vrule width0pt height\ht#1 depth\dp#1}
\begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
    \mathbf{G}=\left[\vphantombox\yourmatrix\right.\overbrace{\usebox\yourmatrix}^{\text{something 1}}\left.\vphantombox\yourmatrix\right]\left.\vphantombox\yourmatrix\right\}{\scriptstyle\text{something 2}}
 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to declare the `\newsavebox` in the preamble?

Comment: `\newsavebox` should be in the preamble, but `\savebox` usually isn't.