# Summarize parts of a table with curly brackets

Tags: tables

I would like to create a table (cf. attached figure) and use curly brakes to summarize some of the cells.

[image]

I did a lot of research and found this solution ([Curly brackets around a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86792/curly-brackets-around-a-table)), but it doesn't help me much as it is only math content and I would like to enter text only.

Does anyone have an idea about how to solve this problem elegantly?

Cheers

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: @Jesse Why the welcome message?

Comment: Well, I see welcome message all the time by fellow users here, not following your question. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one solution where `tikzmark` taking 2 arguments, `brace decoration` and `link` macro that takes 3 arguments are used.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=30pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,array,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand\tikzmark[2]{%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] 
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=2pt] (#1){#2};%
}
\newcommand\link[3]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=1pt}] 
(#1.north west)--(#2.north east)node[above=10pt,midway]{#3};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\def\cwidth{1.5cm} % change this for column width

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{m{\cwidth}|m{\cwidth}|m{\cwidth}|m{\cwidth}|} 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} 
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\tikzmark{b}{\makebox[\cwidth][c]{Fish}}}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\tikzmark{c}{\makebox[\cwidth][c]{Mouse}}}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\tikzmark{d}{\makebox[\cwidth][c]{Bird}}}\\ [1ex]\cline{2-4}
Apple & Here is a sample of text describing an apple&Some text here & some text\\  \cline{2-4}
Banana & Here is a sample of text describing a banana &  & \\ \cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}
\link{b}{c}{Category A}
\link{d}{d}{Category B}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks great and works very well, thank you for your reply!