# Underbrace in denominator with () [] {} (howto)

Tags: math-mode, braces, fractions

I would like to put an underbrace correctly under the denominator of a expression but what I get is wrong because of the (). Alternatively I create another line in the text

`[~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\underbrace{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}_{=(1+3\cos^3\theta)}\]`

but I don't think that's the right method and the text `$(1+3\cos^3\theta)$` yet appear much larger than it should be. The same problem will occur for [sqrt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32645/underbrace-under-sqrt-content) for example.

Than I ask, what is the alternative form to comment expressions like these?

[image]

Comment: Even though it may seem superfluous in small cases like this, it really speeds things up (on both the community and your end) if you supply a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: my fault, but I used the default underbrace option... just selecting the text I want to comment (the denominator in my case, that is inside a \left( \frac{}{denominator} \right) - and than it produces in the .tex \underbrace{denominator}_{'My comment'}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on the automated parentheses sizing here anyways, you can set the size up manually:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\[\biggl(\frac{4\cos^2\theta}{%
\underbrace{4\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta}_{{}=(1+3\cos^2\theta)}}
\biggr)
\]

\lipsum[2]

\[\Biggl(\frac{4\cos^2\theta}{%
\underbrace{4\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta}_{{}=(1+3\cos^2\theta)}}
\Biggr)
\]

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

(Use the variant which you like more. For me, it would be the 1st one, for others, it might be the 2nd one.)

Comment: isn't it `3\cos^` **2** `\theta` ?

Comment: @percusse You mean from mathematical point of view? Probably yes. But now, I have my TeX/typography hat on ;)

Comment: yeah, in general I use the automated parentesis and they work well but for really big equation or in the example I have shown I think your suggestion is more adequated. Thanks ;)

Comment: just wondering, what is lipsum?, poetry? what is it talking about? It is in Latin, right?

Comment: Lorem ipsum is originally a dummy, aperiodic gramatically correct Latin random text generator, which is safe in the sense that it contains nothing naughty or harmful. The `lipsum` package took just 40 paragraphs of this to provide quick dummy text in LaTeX. For more information see http://www.lipsum.com/

Comment: thanks tohecz, I found it interesting... And as you can see I changed my accepted answer also. The reason is because of the simplicity. I think it is better option not to use automated parentesis in such cases. But both answers are useful and I liked.

Answer (score 10):

Smash it!

EDIT: In the spirit of barbara's suggestion, I added a `\,` after the `=` sign in the subscript.

EDIT: In response to tohecz and egreg comments, I added a `\rule`, for cases where underbrace material interferes with material on next line.  The rule depth should correspond to the depth of the underbrace material, in this case, 5.5ex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[\left(\frac{4\cos^2\theta}{%
\smash{\underbrace{4\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta}_{=\,(1+3\cos^3\theta)}}}
\right)%
\rule[-5.5ex]{0ex}{5.5ex}% TO ACCOUNT FOR HEIGHT OF UNDERBRACE MATERIAL
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Placing a `\strut` immediately before the `\smash` will deepen the paren height slightly:

[image]

Comment: spacing around the equals sign would look better if it were preceded by `{}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I see what you are aiming at, but it makes no difference, nor does an enclosing `\mathrel`.  I seem to recall that those features are turned off in `\scriptstyle` mode.

Comment: @barbarabeeton A `\,` accomplished your goal, I think.

Comment: yes, `\,` adds a space, but it's not necessarily the "correct" one.  placing `{}` before the `=` allows tex to do what it is designed to do.

Comment: @barbarabeeton  I understand your point, but in the `\scriptstyle` mode of the subscript, adding the `{}` makes no difference to the spacing around the `=` sign.

Comment: I'm afraid that this solution whould make `=(1+3\cos^3\theta)` collide with the line below it.

Comment: @tohecz That's a good point.  A zero-width `\rule` of the appropriate depth can be added to the end of the line to preclude that.  Gotta go, but I'll look at that later.

Comment: Sorry, but this will make the big object overlap the line below it.