# How to nicely lay out a parentheses-enclosed overbrace/underbrace?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, brackets, overbrace

This:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
$\left( 1                    \right)$
$\left( \underbrace{1}_{456} \right)$
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

which is very ugly. There are several different things one could imagine would happen:

- The underbrace is totally ignored for sizing the parentheses (but of course it counts for spacing to the next line of text).
- The underbrace + actual line fill out the parentheses all the way,  i.e. their center drops below the center of the no-underbrace parentheses and the line.
- The parentheses take the underbrace into account just partially.

I'm assuming the first would be simplest, so - how do I make that happen? Using phantoming perhaps?

Also, if you have another alternative/idiom for how to handle this situation 0 that would be appreciated.

**Note:** This question is about the simple case where the entire contents of the parentheses is covered by a single underbrace.

Comment: maybe this helps? [Underbrace in denominator with () {} (howto)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145865)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: So, I really want to automate [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145866/5640), i.e. to combine `\smash` with measuring the length and applying it late in the extra vertical space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to underbrace the whole subformula between `\left` and `\right`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\parensunderbrace[2]{%
  \vphantom{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}%
  \left(%
    \vphantom{#1}%
    \,\smash{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}\,%
  \right)%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\slowparensunderbrace}[2]{%
  \vphantom{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}%
  \mathpalette\slow@parensunderbrace{{#1}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand\slow@parensunderbrace[2]{%
  \slow@@parensunderbrace#1#2%
}
\newcommand\slow@@parensunderbrace[3]{%
  \left(
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1#2$}%
    \vrule height 1.1\ht\z@ depth \z@ width \z@
    \,\smash{\underbrace{#2}_{#3}}\,
  \right)
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\parensunderbrace
  {\frac{4\cos^2\theta}{4\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta}}
  {=\;(1+3\cos^3\theta)}
\\
\slowparensunderbrace
  {\frac{4\cos^2\theta}{4\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta}}
  {=\;(1+3\cos^3\theta)}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Take your pick.

[image]

A different strategy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\parenswithub}[1]{%
  \mathpalette\parens@withub{#1}%
}
\newcommand\parens@withub[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1#2$}%
  \vphantom{\copy\z@}%
  \left(
    \vrule height 1.1\ht\z@ depth \z@ width \z@
    \smash{#2}%
  \right)
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[3]
\begin{equation*}
\parenswithub{
  1+{\underbrace{\frac{4\cos^2\theta}{4\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta}}_{=\;(1+3\cos^3\theta)}}+2
}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

The additional braces around `\underbrace{...}_{...}` are *always* necessary to get the spacing right.

[image: sss]

Here's what you get with

```
\[
\Biggl(
  1+{\underbrace{\frac{4\cos^2\theta}{4\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta}}_{=\;(1+3\cos^3\theta)}}+2
\Biggr)
\]
```

[image]

Simpler and more efficient.

Comment: Actually, I'm not underbracing the whole thing, but I'll start working based on this.

Comment: @einpoklum That's what I suspected.

Comment: What's the significant benefit of the "slow" version? better spacing?

Comment: So, I'll ask another question about the general case.

Comment: @einpoklum The “slow” version is less efficient, but makes slightly larger parentheses. Not necessary to ask a new question. `;-)` I'd more simply go with `\biggl` and `\biggr`.

Comment: I [asked it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394416/how-to-get-the-spacing-right-with-multiple-underbraces-within-parentheses?noredirect=1&lq=1) after all, since I'm hoping for a better-automated solution.