# How to get the spacing right with multiple underbraces within parentheses?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, brackets, underbrace, overbrace

This question is a generalization of

[How to nicely lay out a parentheses-enclosed overbrace/underbrace?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394409/5640)

Now we have parentheses with some parts of the content, of different heights, having an underbrace. Example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
$\left( 1 \cdot 2 \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot 5^2 \right)$
$\left( \underbrace{1}_{x} \cdot 2 \cdot \underbrace{\frac{3}{4}}_{\int y} \cdot 5^2 \right)$
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

which is very ugly. How can I make the underbraces ignored for the purposes of sizing the parentheses, but count for the space to the next line of text? The solution must allow me to write something like

```
$\magicparens{%
underbrace{1}_{x} \cdot 2 \cdot \underbrace{\frac{3}{4}}_{\int y} \cdot 5^2%
}$
```

and have it work. No manually specifying any sizes or lengths.

Bonus points for a second version which make all the underbraces vertically aligned.

Comment: Well, the easiest answer is “don’t use `\left` and `\right` for the parentheses”…  Do you have some special reason for requiring auto-resizing parentheses?

Comment: @GuM: But I want to, and need to. Why shouldn't I use them?

Comment: because this gives better result (probably what you expected): `\[
\biggl(1 \cdot 2 \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot 5^2 \biggr)
\biggl(\underbrace{1}_{x} \cdot 2 \cdot \underbrace{\frac{3}{4}}_{\int y} \cdot 5^2 \biggr)
\]`

Comment: You also might want to throw in a {\textstyle\frac{3}{4}}.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: In my opinion, `\tfrac` is much too small when the rest of formulae is in `\displaystyle`. But maybe  `\mfrac`would look fine.

Comment: @Zarko: That requires manually setting the parenthesis size, which I want to avoid.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: You're probably right, but I actually have the `\frac` just to create some height variation for the example.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version of `\magicparens` that sets both `\left(` and `\right)` using a `\overbrace`- and `\underbrace`-free makeup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\noubob}[1]{{
  \def\underbrace##1_##2{##1}% Remove subscript associated with \underbrace
  \def\overbrace##1^##2{##1}% Remove superscript associated with \overbrace
  #1}}
\newcommand{\magicparens}[1]{%
  \left(\vphantom{\noubob{#1}}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  #1
  \kern-\nulldelimiterspace\left.\vphantom{\noubob{#1}}\right)
}

\begin{document}

$\left( 1 \cdot 2 \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot 5^2 \right)$

$\left( \underbrace{1}_{x} \cdot 2 \cdot \underbrace{\frac{3}{4}}_{\int y} \cdot 5^2 \right)$

$\magicparens{
  \underbrace{1}_{x} \cdot 2 \cdot \underbrace{\dfrac{3}{4}}_{\int y} \cdot 5^2%
}$

\end{document}
```

Since `$\underbrace{\frac{3}{4}}_{x}$` prints the `\frac`tion in `\displaystyle` while `$\frac{3}{4}$` sets it in `\textstyle`, I've added [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) and forced a `\dfrac`.

Also, the redefinition of `\underbrace`/`\overbrace` inside `\magicparens` requires you to necessarily use `_` and `^` with the respective definitions, even though `\underbrace`/`\overbrace` can naturally be used without them. Of course, one can improve on the redefinition and peek ahead to accommodate for those situations as well.

Comment: No, this doesn't quite work: Your magicparens does not take the height of the `\frac{3}{4}` into account, thus producing parentheses which are too short.

Comment: Also, I doubt this supports nested overbraces and underbraces.

Comment: But +1 already.

Comment: @einpoklum: `\underbrace` and `\overbrace` puts the inner `\frac` in `\displaystyle` even though it should not be in in-line math. So, if you want to possible force everything to be in `\displaystyle`, use `\displaystyle #1` in the definition of `\noubob` or force the fraction to be set the way it should be in the output (say, by adding `\usepackage{amsmath}` and then `\dfrac{3}{4}`).

Comment: @einpoklum: Have you tried it with nested `\overbrace`s/`\underbrace`s?