# underbrace in each subequations in align environment

Tags: align, subequations

I have

```
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

How is it possible to write [image]

using

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
...
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

The code is shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{legalpaper, portrait, margin=1.3in}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\lhead{Small time solution from (15a,b)}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc]{appendix}
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb,amstext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[]{mcode}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amssymb}     
\usepackage{mathtools}               %  new commands %
\newcommand \bprime {\backprime\hspace{-.11em}      }   %  backstroke
\newcommand \xprime {\prime\hspace{-.25em}\backprime}   %  cross
\showoutput
\showboxdepth3

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}   % The style of the section title
  {}                             % a prefix
  {0pt}                          % How much space exists between the prefix and the title
  {Section \thesection:\quad}    % How the section is represented
% Starred variant
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
h^{''}  = \frac{1}{2}  -  \underbrace{\frac{\Big(h(T) + (1-b) \theta (T) \Big)^2}{4 A \sqrt{A \kappa}}}_\text{\Romannum{1}} \Big\{ \underbrace{\frac{(1 - C) \sqrt{\frac{\kappa}{A}}}{(1+(1-C)^2 \frac{\kappa}{A})}}_\text{\Romannum{2}}+ \underbrace{ \frac{C \sqrt{\frac{\kappa}{A}}}{(1+ C^2 \frac{\kappa}{A})}}_\text{\Romannum{3}}  + \underbrace{ \arctan \Big(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\kappa}{A}}}{1 - C (1-C) \frac{\kappa}{A}}\Big)}_\text{\Romannum{4}} \Big\}  - M \hat g, 
\\
\Gamma \theta^{''} = \frac{1}{2} \bigg( \frac{1}{2} - b   - \underbrace{\Big(h(T) + (1-b) \theta (T) \Big)^2}_\text{\Romannum{5}}  \bigg\{ -\frac{1}{2A \kappa} \bigg( \underbrace{\frac{1}{(1+ (1-C)^2 \frac{\kappa}{A})}}_\text{\Romannum{6}} - \underbrace{\frac{1}{(1+C^2 \frac{\kappa}{A})}}_\text{\Romannum{7}}\bigg) 
\\
+ \underbrace{ \frac{(C-b)}{2 A \sqrt{A\kappa}}}_\text{\Romannum{8}}  \Big\{ \underbrace{ \frac{(1 - C) \sqrt{\frac{\kappa}{A}}}{(1+(1-C)^2 \frac{\kappa}{A})}}_\text{\Romannum{9}} + \underbrace{ \frac{C \sqrt{\frac{\kappa}{A}}}{(1+ C^2 \frac{\kappa}{A})}}_\text{\Romannum{10}}  + \underbrace{ \arctan \Big(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\kappa}{A}}}{1 - C (1-C) \frac{\kappa}{A}}\Big) }_\text{\Romannum{11}}\Big\} \bigg\} \bigg) .
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full compilable code that we can play with? Also, should the roman numbering be done by hand or automatically?

Comment: Thanks @Bernard. I have just posted full code. Roman numbers should be shown automatically by `\usepackage{romannum}` package .

Comment: Will you have to  cross-reference these subformulae? And will these numbers have to be reset at each equation?

Comment: Yes @Bernard, they have to be used in subequations like above. The reason for that is the equations are so long and I have to get `(a), (b)` tags for these two equations above. Equation numbering should be done automatically when compiling not manually.

Comment: I personally would recommend using `tikzmark` to add the braces. That way you can separate the drawing from the content. Examples include: [Underbrace under sqrt content](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207211/4301), [How avoid that the Underbrace Outside the delimiters $| |$ appear inside the delimiters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208164/4301) and [Using \underbrace with table columns](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62576/4301).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Introduced a new command `\romanbrace`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{fudge}
\renewcommand\thefudge{\textnormal{\Roman{fudge}}}
\newcommand{\ouch}{\refstepcounter{fudge}\thefudge}
\newcommand{\romanbrace}[1]{\underbrace{#1}_{\ouch}}
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
 y&= t_hi_s + i_s + \romanbrace{c_r a_z y!} \\
 z&= \romanbrace{s_tu_pi_d}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you've solved the OP's first issue, viz., how to get the "label" below each underbrace to be incremented automatically and to be displayed in Roman numerals. I think the OP also wants to be able to cross-reference the braced items; can your approach accomplish this? (Incidentally, I've made your code a bit more "LaTeX-y"; feel free to revert.)

Comment: `\romanbrace` -- nice touch! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions

- Get rid of as much visual clutter as possible. Omit unneeded parentheses, keep the size of various groups of parentheses consistent, and assure that the underbraces are all at the same depth. (In the code below, look for a couple of `\vphantom` statements.) Choose line breaks so that none of the equation material protrudes into the margin.
- Don't load any given package more than once. Also, don't load packages in a redundant way: the `amstext` package is loaded automatically by the `amsmath` package which, in turn, is loaded automatically by the `mathtools` package.
- Align the `=` symbols in rows 1 and 3 relative to each other, and indent the material on lines 2 and 4.
- Use a dedicated counter -- called `romcount` in the code below -- and set its appearance to be uppercase-Roman. Then, set up a macro (called `\romantag` in the code below) increments and displays this counter; use this macro in the second argument of the various `\underbrace` statements.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{legalpaper, portrait, margin=1.3in}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{Small time solution from (15a,b)}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}

\usepackage[titletoc,toc]{appendix}
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb}%%%,amstext}
%%%\usepackage{amsmath}
%%%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[]{mcode}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%%%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{enumerate}
%%%\usepackage{amssymb}     
\usepackage{mathtools}  

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage{nameref}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}   % The style of the section title
  {}                             % a prefix
  {0pt}                          % How much space exists between the prefix and the title
  {Section \thesection:\quad}    % How the section is represented
% Starred variant
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {}

\newcounter{romcount}
\renewcommand\theromcount{\Roman{romcount}}
\newcommand\romantag{\stepcounter{romcount}\textnormal{\theromcount}}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
h''  &= \frac{1}{2}  - M \hat g  \notag\\
&\qquad-
\underbrace{\frac{\bigl(h(T) + (1-b) \theta (T) \bigr)^2}{4 A \sqrt{A \kappa}}}_{\romantag} \biggl\{ 
\underbrace{\frac{(1 - C) \sqrt{\frac{\kappa}{A}}}{1+(1-C)^2 \frac{\kappa}{A}}}_{\romantag}+ 
\underbrace{ \frac{C \sqrt{\frac{\kappa}{A}}}{1+ C^2 \frac{\kappa}{A}}}_{\romantag}  + 
\underbrace{ \arctan \frac{\sqrt{\frac{\kappa}{A}}}{1 - C (1-C) \frac{\kappa}{A}}}_{\romantag} \biggr\} \,, \label{eq:first}\\
\Gamma \theta'' &= 
\frac{1}{2} \bigg[ \frac{1}{2} - b   - 
\underbrace{\bigl(h(T) + (1-b) \theta (T) \vphantom{\frac{1}{\frac{\kappa}{A}}}\bigr)^2}_{\romantag}  
\biggl\{ -\frac{1}{2A \kappa} \bigg( 
\underbrace{\frac{1}{1+ (1-C)^2 \frac{\kappa}{A}}}_{\romantag} - 
\underbrace{\frac{1}{1+C^2 \frac{\kappa}{A}}}_{\romantag}\bigg)  \notag \\
&\qquad+ 
\underbrace{ \frac{C-b}{2 A \sqrt{A\kappa}}\vphantom{\frac{1}{\frac{\kappa}{A}}}}_{\romantag}  \biggl( 
\underbrace{ \frac{(1 - C) \sqrt{\frac{\kappa}{A}}}{1+(1-C)^2 \frac{\kappa}{A}}}_{\romantag} + 
\underbrace{ \frac{C \sqrt{\frac{\kappa}{A}}}{1+ C^2 \frac{\kappa}{A}}}_{\romantag}  + 
\underbrace{ \arctan \frac{\sqrt{\frac{\kappa}{A}}}{1 - C (1-C) \frac{\kappa}{A}} }_{\romantag}
\biggr) \biggr\} \bigg] \,. \label{eq:second}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: All good comments.